# How to get each sheet URL and set it in range A1 automatically using googlesheet script for all the sheets in spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to use Googlesheet script to exctract each sheet URL and paste it in range A1 of each sheet so I can collect them later in one MAIN sheet

Please notice the sheet name "Main" shall be ignored in the script so the script will not get this sheet URL

I try here to make the script but it give me error

```js
function getUrl() {
  const urls = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets().map(s => s.getUrl());
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets().forEach(s => {
    s.getRange('B3').setValue(s.getUrl());
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the URL of each sheet except for "Main" sheet.
- You want to put the URL into cell "A1" of each sheet.

#### Modification points:

- Unfortunately, Class Sheet has no method of `getUrl`.
- You say `I want to use Googlesheet script to exctract each sheet URL and paste it in range A1 of each sheet`. But, in your scirpt, `s.getRange('B3').setValue(s.getUrl());` is used.

When these points are reflected in a sample script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

```js
function getUrl() {
  const ignoreSheet = "Main"; // This is from your question.

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const baseUrl = ss.getUrl();
  const sheets = ss.getSheets();
  sheets.forEach(sheet => {
    if (sheet.getSheetName() != ignoreSheet) {
      sheet.getRange("A1").setValue(`${baseUrl}#gid=${sheet.getSheetId()}`);
    }
  });
}
```

- In this case, the URL of each sheet is created by "getUrl() of Class Spreadsheet" and "getSheetId() of Class Sheet".
- When this script is run, the URLs of each sheet except for "Main" sheet are retrieved and each URL is put into cell "A1" of each sheet.

#### References:

- [getUrl() of Class Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#geturl)
- [getSheetId() of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getSheetId())

### Added:

About your following 2nd question,

> I have another question if you allow me please, if I want to ignore multiple sheets instead of one sheet only, for example "Main" & "CS" Sheets then what shall I do??

In this case, how about the following sample script?

```js
function getUrl() {
  const ignoreSheets = ["Main", "CS"]; // This is from your question.

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const baseUrl = ss.getUrl();
  const sheets = ss.getSheets();
  sheets.forEach(sheet => {
    if (!ignoreSheets.includes(sheet.getSheetName())) {
      sheet.getRange("A1").setValue(`${baseUrl}#gid=${sheet.getSheetId()}`);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you are genius, this is so perfect same as I want, it solved all my problems

Comment: I have another question if you allow me please, if I want to ignore multiple sheets instead of one sheet only, for example "Main" & "CS" Sheets then what shall I do?? I am really sorry for disturbing you again

Comment: @Shawa About your 2nd question of `I have another question if you allow me please, if I want to ignore multiple sheets instead of one sheet only, for example "Main" & "CS" Sheets then what shall I do??`, I added a sample script in my answer. Please confirm it.

Comment: @Shawa Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your 2nd question was resolved. Thank you, too.